# Software Installer - Make separate .exe for each file

Tags: installation, windows-installer, installshield

Looking for an installer that will take any number of files in a folder and make each file into an exe (not put them all into one exe). Will any installers easily do this? I haven't been able to find a feature name for this, so it's made it difficult to determine from a feature list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Nullsoft installer](http://goo.gl/h983h). About anything can be scripted w/ it.